# How do I correctly include a dash in an object key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

When I try to use a code like this:

```
jQuery.post("http://mywebsite.com/", {
    array-key: "hello"
});
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

I tried surrounding the key in quotation marks, but nothing happened. I'd like to know if it's because of some other mistake I am making at the other website or because that's not how to include a dash in an object's key. And if it's not I'd like to know how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just FYI that's an object, not an array. Also `I tried surrounding the key in quotation marks` should have worked fine.

Comment: Quotes around key will fix problem.  That being said, I wouldn't get in the habit of using hyphens in key names.  that is just bad practice.

Comment: You can only use unquoted keys if the key would also work as the name of a variable.  That means only letters, numbers, and underscores; if there are hyphens (dashes) or any other punctuation besides underscores, you need the quotes.

Comment: @MikeBrant this looks like the client side of an API call, so Nadroev may not have control over the choice of key names..

Comment: Which also means if you want to access a property of an object you need to use `myObj['hyphenated-property]` which is ugly and should be avoided. EDIT im aware he's not consuming the object in the client but worth noting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery.post("http://mywebsite.com/", {"array-key": "hello"});
```

should be correct. If this doesn't work, the issue is not with your request.