# Score or minus symbol in ajax data

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im trying to build a ajax call using some $post data that require the score separator and always face an issue of wrong syntax.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "register.php",
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { 
            register-username: name,
            register-email: email,
        },
        success: function(response) {
        },
        error: function(){
        }
    });
```

i wonder how i can use those register-username and register-email without having a syntax error. Changing those for no separator is not an option.

Comment: Put them in quotes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I correctly include a dash in an object key in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34024434/how-do-i-correctly-include-a-dash-in-an-object-key-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks Nick Bailey i may be too tired i tryed everything exept that thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use quotes

```
 data: { 
   "register-username": name,
   "register-email": email,
 },
```